# How can I get the creation date of an Amazon S3 Blob?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

How can I get the creation date of an Amazon S3 Blob ? I want to see the date my blob was created.

Is this possible ?

Comment: I was just wondering doesn't `FileInfo` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do a HEAD request on the blob if you are using the API. I don't know what you are using - direct REST or perhaps some C# library?

With the AWS client, you can log in and see the 'last modified' date. This is the creation date - AWS S3 only allows atomic - whole changes to each blob.

If you don't have versioning on, no data is retained, other than perhaps log files, that would show the dates of other blobs uploaded with the same file name (key). So perhaps you are out of luck.. it depends on what you mean by 'creation'.

Comment: I figured this out and forgot to answer the question. However since you beat me to it you get the answer points. GJ =D

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket-name --prefix Path/filter/here/ --query "Contents[].LastModified"
```